# Common-LISP - Subtraction

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this function:

```
(defun test (variable)
  (cond
    ((null variable) nil)
    ((< (- 12 (other-function variable) 3) 0) 1)
    (t (- 12 (other-function variable) 3))
  )
)
```

The idea is, if the result of the subtraction of 12 with the value of the function with 3 is less than 0, it returns 1. Else, it will just make the subtraction.
The "other-function" returns a number.
When I run this function, lispworks freezes. But if I run the function without the first condition:

```
(defun test (variable)
  (cond
    ((null variable) nil)
    (t (- 12 (other-function variable) 3))
  )
)
```

it makes the subtraction without any problem.
Can someone help?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I tried this way with let:

```
(defun test (variable)
(let (x (other-function variable))
  (cond
    ((null variable) nil)
    ((< (- 12 x 3) 0) 1)
    (t (- 12 x 3)))
  )
)
```

But I still got the same problem with lispworks which is, it freezes. When I run without the following condition:

```
 ((< (- 12 x 3) 0) 1)
```

This function works correctly.

Comment: Seems to me that the problem lies in `other-function` rather than `test`. Instead of doing the same twice you could bind the value in a `let` and reuse that variable.

Comment: @Sylwester i will add the way i tried with let in the question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene edited.

Comment: @MarB Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/iZguMV

Comment: And the definition for `other-function` where the bug most likely is and perhaps an example og what argument you pass to `test`?

Comment: Please check your `let` form.

Comment: Something is wrong with `other-function`.

Comment: Your `let` is wrong, though it is not the main problem. To test if `other-function` is the problem, substitute it with other function like `(lambda (foo) (+ foo 1))`

Answer (score 3):

**Unless you come up with your full code and a test case, this can't be reproduced.**

```
CL-USER 1 > (lisp-implementation-type)
"LispWorks"

CL-USER 2 > (defun test (variable)
              (cond
               ((null variable) nil)
               ((< (- 12 (other-function variable) 3) 0) 1)
               (t (- 12 (other-function variable) 3))))
TEST

CL-USER 3 > (defun other-function (foo) (+ foo 1))
OTHER-FUNCTION

CL-USER 4 > (test 5)
3

CL-USER 5 > (test 500)
1
```

Also: LispWorks usually does not 'freeze' on an error.